# set radio in lightning data table from object record

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, radio-button

I have a data table with `max-row-selection="1"` attribute to show radio button. Once user select radio button for a row and save that selected record checkbox field will become true in the salesforce.

Now I want to show the selected radio button for the row for which it was checked earlier when the data table loads. How can I do this?

I have tried to set selectedRows variable with the selected record Id when data loads during connectedcallback but it doesn't get selected.

```xml
 <lightning-datatable max-row-selection="1" key-field="Id" data={dummyData} columns={cols} selected-rows={selectedRows}> </lightning-datatable>
```

```javascript
handleGetInfo() {
    getInfo({recordId: this.recordId})
    .then((result) => {
        this.dummyData = result;
        this.error = undefined;
        for(let d of this.dummyData ){
            if(d.checked__c){
                this.selectedRows = d.Id;
                console.log('handleGetInfo '+ d.Id);
            }
        }        
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        this.error = error;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            this.selectedRows = [];
            this.selectedRows.push(d.Id);
```

I forgot that *selectedRows* stores a list of Ids. So doing the above change set the default radio during loading time.